# SystemBarTint Error

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I use the library from https://github.com/jgilfelt/SystemBarTint.
Now I can't create an instance of `SystemBarTintManager` because of a Resource Not Found Exception.

For more information, please ask what you need.

My Error:

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
```

Here I create the Manager:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // create our manager instance after the content view is set
    SystemBarTintManager tintManager = new SystemBarTintManager(this);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in your metod onCreate:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        SystemBarTintManager tintManager = new SystemBarTintManager(this);
        tintManager.setStatusBarTintEnabled(true);
        // Holo light action bar color is #DDDDDD
        int actionBarColor = Color.parseColor("#ff8800");
        tintManager.setStatusBarTintColor(actionBarColor);
  }
```

Comment: StatusBar color is not changing